# how to find memory leaks in a very slow application?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, memory-leak-detector

I have a program, written in C, it uses Berkeley-Db, glib-2, and libxml-2. It is a search indexer which makes NLP with syntactic and semantic analysis, and stores conceptual structures in search indices instead of words.

However, I have a problem -- after a day or so, my program runs out of memory.

When I try to run my program under valgrind, it works **very** slow, it seems to me, that 10 times slower than with normal run.

All my attempts to check for memory-leaks (made for weeks under valgrind or so) didn't show any leaks.

Does anybody know some tools that can help me in this situation?

Comment: Is it possible that it's not a leak, just that you've plain used all your memory? Occam's razor, and all that.

Comment: @tbert I don't think so, doesn't look like this. Memory is freed after each document.

Comment: It can be that your address space gets fragmented and even though you do have free memory, you cannot allocate big-enough contiguous chunks of the address space for your buffers. It might be a good idea to go 64-bit if your app is currently 32-bit.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze My app is 64-bit.

Comment: I use Deleaker for similar cases...

Comment: @MastAvalons Thank you. Ubfortunately, Deleaker is designed for MS Visual C++, not for pure C on linux, which is my case.

Comment: Try gdb. It's similar powerfull debugger but for Linux :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my solution would be:

```
#define malloc(size) mymalloc(size, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__)
... (realloc, calloc, free)

void *mymalloc(size_t size, char *file, char *function, int line)
{
  void *data = malloc(size);
  addList(data, size, file, function, line);
  return data;
}

void myfree(void *data)
{
  removeList(data);
  free(data);
}

void debugalloc()
{
  printList();
}
```

the removeList() would search for "data" in the global list and remove it, or gives a warning. with "debugalloc();" you should print the whole list (and normally it should be empty, or well filled with what you expect it to have).

**Another option**:
your memory management gets fragmented, ... (upps, Alexey Frunze wrote that just a second ago in the comments section.)

**EDITH**: XML

I made a comment about DOM and SAX, and I have the feeling just to expand this comment:

```
<head><data>...</data><data>...</data>......<data>...</data></head>
```

is an excellent candidate for SAX. In DOM, the whole XML will be read and converted into memory, which can lead very quickly to fragmented memory, if < data > itself is structured with different sized values. it may happen, that your operating system's memory modell will work against mallocing small amounts of memory.

With SAX, you only load portions of data into memory and get rid of it as soon as it is consumed. But your implementation must change from traversing the Document into a kind of State Machine with feeding (< data >) and consuming/processing (< / data >).

Comment: Maybe I should try this... And what should I do to determine that my memory gets fragmented? Also, what to do with glib/db4/libxml2 structures that are malloced within the libraries, but not within my app?

Comment: libxml2 has its own malloc-callback. (you can overwrite the functions, libxml2 is using, with your mymalloc counterparts) (see: http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlmemory.html)

Comment: about your XML: SAX or DOM? if you use DOM and you have a memory-problem (DOM is very fragmenting the buffer) you may sometimes have the option to change to SAX.

Comment: libxml2 has its own malloc-callback, but what about db4 and glib2? I use SAX and sometimes DOM, but XML processing is used only on initialization. Two xml files are read in each thread -- one with constituent grammar (about 2000 nodes), and one with punctuation (the latter is read with SAX). NLP machinery is reinitialized after each 5 documents processed, so these files are reloaded. However, when using DOM, I free the xmlDoc structure within the function that loads XML.

Comment: sorry, I am out. glib2 and db4 I never used, so someone else must take over.